# Kendo datasoure and grid inline edit, adding a new item, always creates a new row with id 0

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo datasoure with kendo grid for inline editing.
When i add/create a new row, the new row is posted to my create URL(i am using post). my problem is in the query params, the value of the id field is zero, is there a way to make it empty or remove it from the query string, in some js event.before posting it to the create url.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the ID should be an auto-increment field, in which case you wouldn't insert the id into the database. Then, your datasource should have something like this (undocumented method) to refresh the grid after create, which will populate your ID field with the database-assigned ID:

```
create: {
    url: "[your create url]",
    complete: function(e){
        $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
    }
}
```

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, the latest KendoUI's [datasource](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource) transport methods don't have a parameter called 'complete'. You have to use jquery ajax request. Also, you can only use either KendoUI's trasnport methods or jquery ajax. combining won't work. For instance:

```
create:function (options) {
    $.ajax({
        url:base + entityName + "/create",
        data:"models=" + kendo.stringify(options.data.models),
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        async:false,
        global:false,
        success:function (result) {
            if (result.errors == null) {
                //GridHandlers.refreshGrid(gridId);
                options.success(result);
            } else {
                GridHandlers.accounceAndResume(gridId, result.errors);
            }
        },
        error:function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error: " + (errorThrown ? errorThrown : xhr.status));
            GridHandlers.accounceAndResume(gridId, "Could not create new record. Connection problem!");
        }
    });
},
```

what is important to you is what you do in the success method. Happy coding!